# Why does my JS 'click event' only run once?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, mouseclick-event

I created a click event that opens a previously 'hidden' div and closes it again once you click the same button.

However, it only runs once (one open and one close) - I'm at a loss to explain why it doesn't work if I click it again.

```
let readMore = document.getElementById('clickAbout');
let moreInfo = document.getElementById('about');
let changeSepa = document.getElementById('sepChange');


readMore.addEventListener('click', function(){
    changeSepa.style.height = '2rem';
    if (moreInfo.className == "") {
        moreInfo.className = "open";
        moreInfo.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        
            moreInfo.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: When you click it the second time, you don't remove the `open` class.

Comment: Why are you changing the style explicitly? Make that part of the `.open` CSS style.

Comment: Don't use `className`, use `classList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because you're checking if className == "", but you are modifying the className to be "open". On the second click it checks the className which is now "open" and goes to the else block. On the third click you expect for it to go into the first block but the className is still "open".

For an easy fix just change the className in the else block

```
else {
  moreInfo.className = "";  
  moreInfo.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Also i suggest you make use of the `classList` property on elements
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

using the class list it could look like this:

```
readMore.addEventListener("click", function () {
  changeSepa.style.height = "2rem";
  if (moreInfo.className == "") {
    moreInfo.classList.add("open");
    moreInfo.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    moreInfo.classList.remove("open");
    moreInfo.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Or even

```
readMore.addEventListener("click", function () {
  changeSepa.style.height = "2rem";
  moreInfo.classList.toggle("open");
  if (moreInfo.className == "") {
    moreInfo.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    moreInfo.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```